# full width and fixed height video without cropping in html5

Tags: html, css

Need to embed a video in div of full width 100% and fixed height in html5.
we can achieve using overflow: hidden, but the video is cropped. how can we achieve this without cropping and stretching of video inside the div?

Comment: <div><video><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></div>         div{height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;width: 100%;}      video{    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    object-fit: cover;}

Comment: hi kaiido, from this code , the video is embed inside div within height and width, but it will cropped in top and bottom. so didnt get full resolution of video

Comment: I could help if you made a snippet

Comment: FIDDLE with Video: https://jsfiddle.net/sz78tLe0/

Comment: use contain not cover

Comment: contain will show your video as it should be but it won't be 100% width, if you want it 100% width you need to use 'fill' but your object will be skewed depending on the size of the browser  https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/sz78tLe0/2/

Comment: Rachel Gallen is right, use contain, which is the default, if you don't want to crop or stretch the video. If you always want it to fill 100% width, then you have no choice than crop or stretch the video (or do you want the video to have a bigger height than its container?)

Comment: appreciate.. rachel , Kaiido.